# Display the record in column for grouping only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a large table with a basic structure like :

```
Aircode  FlightNumber Locator Title
A01      F01          A       Miss
A01      F01          A       Mr
A01      F01          B       Miss
A01      F01          B       Miss
A01      F02          A       Mr
A01      F02          A       Mr
A01      F02          C       Mr
A02      F01          A       Mr
```

I wonder if it is possible to create a query and returns the group names only once in MSSQL , such as :

```
Aircode  FlightNumber Locator Title
A01      F01          A       Miss
                              Mr
                      B       Miss
                              Miss
         F02          A       Mr
                              Mr
                      C       Mr
A02      F01          A       Mr
```

After the some search I found method using Row_Number() Over (Partition by) , but I get very confused in this case with multiple groups as I can't think of way to hide multiple values from multiple columns. I wonder if there is a proper way of proceeding this piece of data.

EDIT 1
By applied CTE and ROW_NUMBER method , it returns blank records with no values first , then Title , Locator etc. Example:

```
Aircode  FlightNumber Locator Title


                              Miss
                              Miss
                      A       Mr
 A01       F01        B       Miss
 A02       F02        B       Miss
```

Comment: Since whatever presentation tier has to loop through these rows in order to render them, why not just have logic there that - within the loop - decides whether or not to show values based on what was in the previous row? Presentation stuff doesn't really belong in SQL...

Comment: it seems your actual table has some null values for Airfore, to which row in result does that record belong?

Comment: @Farhęg , sorry my first table was incorrect. I have updated it. And for Aircode contains NULL values they should not be shown in the result.

Comment: Ok, so [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29268591/3208640) should work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try assigning a `ROW_NUMBER` to each partition level and only show the text for the first one:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
     [Aircode]
    ,[FlightNumber]
    ,[Locator]
    ,[Title]
    ,[r1] = ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER(PARTITION BY [Aircode] 
                    ORDER BY [AirCode])
    ,[r2] = ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER(PARTITION BY [Aircode], [FlightNumber] 
                    ORDER BY [FlightNumber])
    ,[r3] = ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER(PARTITION BY [Aircode], [FlightNumber], [Locator]
                    ORDER BY [Locator])
  FROM <table>
)
SELECT  [Aircode]      = CASE WHEN [r1] = 1 THEN [Aircode] ELSE '' END
       ,[FlightNumber] = CASE WHEN [r2] = 1 THEN [FlightNumber] ELSE '' END
       ,[Locator]      = CASE WHEN [r3] = 1 THEN [Locator] ELSE '' END
       ,[Title]
FROM cte
ORDER BY cte.[Aircode], cte.[FlightNumber], cte.[Locator], cte.[Title]
```

Comment: Nice idea , i have tried this query and it really returns the duplicated records only once , however the group-name records are only showing at bottom of table,