# Show GroupBy common value once in a column

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to achieve the second table from the first one. I am grouping by some data and want to show the repeated values only once.

```
Aircode  FlightNumber Locator Title
A01      F01          A       Miss
A01      F01          A       Mr
A01      F01          B       Miss
A01      F01          B       Miss
A01      F02          A       Mr
A01      F02          A       Mr
A01      F02          C       Mr
A02      F01          A       Mr


Aircode  FlightNumber Locator Title
A01      F01          A       Miss
                              Mr
                      B       Miss
                              Miss
         F02          A       Mr
                              Mr
                      C       Mr
A02      F01          A       Mr
```

I couldn't search a appropriate result for this. Not sure if there was any question for this in MySQL.

I found a link for MSSQL but I don't want to complicate the query that much. The link to that question is [Display the record in column for grouping only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268501/display-the-record-in-column-for-grouping-only-once)

This is a relevant question.

Is it possible to make this ?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Such display issues should not be dealt with in SQL, but outside in your GUI.

Comment: I completely agree but cannot infuse common sense to bosses, right :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in fields names to return `null` when new row has old value to create the second table:

```
 SET @aircode_var = '' , @flight_var='' , @locator_var='' ;
 SELECT if(@aircode_var=Aircode, null,@aircode_var:=Aircode),
      if(@flight_var=FlightNumber , null ,@flight_var:=FlightNumber ),
      if(@locator_var=Locator , null ,@locator_var:=Locator ),
      Title
 FROM tablename
 group by Aircode , FlightNumber , Locator
```

Result must be look like this one:

```
 A01    F01     A       Miss
 null   null    null    Mr
 null   null    B       Miss
 ....
```

Note: `:=` assign new value to variable, and `=` is logical for `IF`.

(*) Query updated with new `SET` command in the first line, because of bug in multiple running query and missed results.

Comment: Just because you *can*, it doesn't follow that you *should*

Comment: @MohaMad : Now... This works fine when we have multiple data in the required field but if we have only one kind then it shows correctly for the first execution but for the second time it makes the first value NULL as well !

Comment: add `SET @aircode_var = '' , @flight_var='' , @locator_var='' ;` before your Next Query Executing. It's flushing variables and will works in many executions.